# Can't edit java code-file is somehow empty

Tags: java, file

Hopefully this has a trivial answer: I have a java file which I wrote and edited a while back, but at some point I tried to open it recently and it says it is 0kb and no code is displayed in the IDE(i tried more than one). What is really confusing is that it runs perfectly from command line. It was just quite a small GuiApp, and all the class files are still there. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please tell us which IDE you are using...

Comment: and how you tried to open your .java file

Comment: " it runs perfectly from command line" - that just means the class file is still ok. That doesn't mean the .java file can't be empty. How that .java file got deleted is something we can't say, everything we can do is make wild guesses.

Comment: @Thomas, So he can open the `.class` file and copy-paste the code again into `.java` file.

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee' ... whut? you think the content of a .class file is identical to the content of the .java file? maybe you should look into what exactly compilation does

Comment: @Stultuske,Sorry, I was thinking in java jdk classes it is open because it is have a source of java file, he can open class file but not in direct way maybe by using a decompiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decompile the .class file and you will see your code.

Fair warning, this will be 'compiled code' so expect to see many changes in your code as the compiler has the liberty to optimise code where it sees fit. You may see it use the StringBuilder class for example where you simply concated a couple of strings, etc.

Comment: not to mention that not all decompilers are able to understand the latest versions of Java. But the question is actually about the issue when opening a java file, it's not about decompilation.

Comment: @Stultuske And how do you propose we answer the mystery of disappearing code? It's gone, nothing else to it. OP needs to salvage his code, he needs to decompile. What decompiler he uses is up to him.

Comment: the question might very well be the OP thinking there is a bug in his IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, will try using a decompiler